# vim to use removing patterns with varying length in a line

Tags: regex, vim

Trying this for quite a while..

I have a line like:

```
text1 GXP_64749(abc/cde)Symbol text2 GXP_6474449(fgh/ijk)Symbol text3 GXP_649(ab/ilky)Symbol
```

I want to have:

```
text1 text2 text3
```

I tried in different variations

```
:s/GXP.*Symbol//
:s/GXP.{,20}Symbol//
```

but I either get

```
Pattern not found
```

or (missing the `text2` in the middle):

```
text1 text3
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a non-greedy quantifier instead of `*`, that in [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) is `{-}` :

```
:s/\v\s+GXP.{-}Symbol//g
```

It yields:

```
text1 text2 text3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:s/\s*GXP.{-}Symbol//g
```

This regular expression first matches 0+ pieces of whitespace, then matches `GXP`, then lazily matches 0+ of anything (lazily means it stops as soon as possible, and then matches (stops the lazy match) `Symbol`.  The `g` modifier is needed to search globally.

**Note:** updated `.*?` to `.{-}` thanks to @PeterRincker's tip.

Comment: `.*?` would work great if Vim used perlish regexes. Vim's equivalent is `.\{-}`. See `:h perl-patterns`

Comment: Thank you @PeterRincker, that's why I contribute on SO -- learn something every day :) updating answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
:s/ GXP[^ ]*Symbol//g
```

`[^ ]*` means: any character except Space